# errors in the WCAG building process

Tags: xslt, accessibility, wcag

I am trying to Generate WCAG 2.1 and related documents from master branch of the github repository: https://github.com/w3c/wcag, but get the following error:

> generate-techniques.xslt:423:16: Fatal Error!
>   A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of fn:normalize-space() ("The button text matches the fi...", "Rendered example").

I'm using Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.5+windows 10

Comment: Well, file an issue on github. Or what kind of help are you looking for here? That code is https://github.com/w3c/wcag/blob/master/xslt/generate-techniques.xslt#L423 and calls https://github.com/w3c/wcag/blob/master/xslt/base.xslt#L30 which intentionally tries to return any kind of heading so whoever then wrote `<xsl:if test="normalize-space($heading) != ''">` seems to expect that function returns only one element.

Comment: You can try to change that call to e.g. `<xsl:if test="normalize-space($heading[1]) != ''">`, that might avoid the problem with the XSLT. No idea whether the XSLT output then is as intended. Or whether the XML input to the XSLT is kind of broken as it has more than one heading as a child of the `html:section[@class='example']`.